# Custom Configuration for CK Editor 4

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, editor, wysiwyg

I created a little module in Drupal 7 to use a custom config file for CK editor. This works, because I can adapt the UI Color or can activate SCAYT and edit some options imn SCAYT.

So I think this custom config file is working OK. 
But now I tried to do saomething with the plugIns in the install folder of CK ... But it seems that these are not active or not loaded. 
Is there any difference between assemble a ck editor via CK Builder and download the plugins manually and activate the plugins via

config.ExtraPlugin = 'floating-tools';

I have the expierence, that a lot of plugins, which I download are not active  ....

Why there is no visible control in settings dependig plugins????
How to check if a plugin is loaded.
Is there any thing to do after some configuration in custom config file was made so the changings take effect?

...sorry it seems I dont understand the way to use the ck builder ... but I´m confused ... today I uploaded my build-config.js and added and reduce some plugins ... then downloaded a new version 4.5.4. .. ??? I used 4.5.3 before ...

Then I pasted the new CK-Editor into the libraries folder of my drupal installation and nothing works ... no CKeditor comes up for editing content ...

I dont no how to handle this. Where I can deactivate the plugins so I may find a faulty plugin? Maybe the skin is the reason but I did not changed this ...

Another question: I can put the old version of CK Editor back into may libraries folder and it worked again ... but is it possible to simple copy a plugin to the plugins folder ? Is it activated then and worked ? Or have I configure something else.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with the case of the properties that you try to use: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins